# Get intersection of 2 tif files

Tags: python, gdal, qgis, satellite-image

I have 2 tiff files which use the EPSG:32637 coordinate system. I want to clip their intersection region and save it separately as tiff files.
[image]
As a result, the output tiff files have the same upper_left and lower_right coordinates and the same size. Can you suggest ways to get the intersection and save them in separate tiff files??? I don't know how to do this.

Comment: I don't know how to get intersections and save them in separate tiff files.

Comment: How do you know the overlaping area / intersection is always the same size of the original images ?

Comment: Both are Maxar satellite images with the same resolution. Both rasters are identical in size.

Comment: I assume each pixel has a coordinate - if so, you could load the tifs as 2D numpy arrays and look for matching coordinates in both images - save all matching indices of both images and write a new image based on the saved indices

Comment: But like the image of your question suggests - since the images overlap, you will loose some pixel. This means the actual size of the "overlap image" will be smaller then the original images. Depending of the base between the images the resulting images will get smaller the bigger the base between the images is

Comment: In tiff files you have a value for a pixel, and a mapping of that pixel to some coordinate. When you load it in the NumPy array, you only have pixel value and the coordinate mapping is lost. Secondly, I want that both intersections must have the same size although they will be smaller than the original tiff file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251885/discussion-between-muhammad-muneeb-ur-rahman-and-chris).

Comment: Please share your images if you would like some assistance!

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the boundarys of the tifs as a Polygon with [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/447754/better-workflow-for-extracting-boundary-of-raster-in-qgis) Worfklow.
2. Get intersection with the Tool Intersection `(native:intersection)`
3. Clip the tifs `gdal:cliprasterbymasklayer`

All the tools you need you'll find in the QGIS processing-Toolbox!

For future GIS-Questions you should ask [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com).